# Power BI Grid not Showing on Right

Tags: powerbi

Does anyone know why my Power BI table is missing part of the grid, particularly on the far right value?

How did you go about fixing this?

**Edit #1:**

The border lines. They show up in the first 2 clumns but not the 3rd.

I am using a table visualization.

[image: Table missing part of grid]

Comment: Missing value? or missing cell? or missing border lines? please make your question clear.

Comment: Edited post to include more details.

Comment: Can you provide a sample report with small amount of sample data having this scenario. Otherwise it is very difficult to diagnose the issue.

Comment: That is the sample data in the image. I literally created a table, manually input those 3 records and then tried to format it by using the Grid.

Comment: I have asked for the report file (pbix) if possible. With small amount of sample data and the grid line issue.